# Will unnecessary Serial.print() statements slow down my program?

Tags: serial, performance

I have lots of `Serial.print()` and `Serial.println()` statements throughout my (rather large) program for debugging when things fail. I've commented out the `Serial.begin()` statement so I don't slow down execution by running a serial port. However, I'd like to leave the `Serial.print()` calls so I only have to uncomment `Serial.begin()` later on.

If there is no Serial port active on the device, are the `Serial.print()` lines still executed at runtime, or does the compiler ignore them? Is there any performance advantage to explicitly commenting out those lines?

Comment: You may write your program in machine code instead then you'd know exactly what the microcontroller is doing.

Comment: What has that got to do with Serial prints?

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no `USART` wasn't enabled so skip all `print`s. Everything must be done anyways (calls, conversions to strings, writes to `UDR` - `USART Data Register`). It is just not sent outside by `USART` and it doesn't have to wait for `UDRE` (`USART Data Register Empty` flag) so it might be slightly faster.

You can use similar technique as Loggers - log level variable and `if`s (this can be changed runtime).

Or you can use macros:

```
// comment out this line, if you want to show logs:
#define NDEBUG

#ifdef NDEBUG
  #define LOG(...)
  #define LOGLN(...)
#else
  #define LOG(...) Serial.print(__VA_ARGS__)
  #define LOGLN(...) Serial.println(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

And later:

```
LOG(F("Something: 0x"));
LOGLN(variable, HEX);
```

And how it looks after macro substitution? For code:

```
if (...) LOG(F("something")); else LOG(F("something else"));
```

With NDEBUG defined it's expanded to:

```
if (...) ; else ;
```

And without NDEBUG defined it's expanded to:

```
if (...) Serial.print(F("something")); else Serial.print(F("something else"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot know what the situation with the device is at runtime. The function itself must determine that, so the call *will* take place, with arguments and everything. A well-written function would test early on whether there was anything to do, and if not then return early - but that still wastes time.

The norm in programming is to have two versions of the code: one labelled "DEBUG", which has lots of `print()`s, and one labelled "RELEASE", which uses language contructs to ignore them. This is achieved a number of different ways - but Arduino doesn't really support this out of the box.

@KIIV's answer, using `#define`, is one way to do this. The problem with it comes when you have multiple modules, or are using libraries that themselves do their own `print()`s. If you only have your main sketch, then it would work fairly well.

Answer (score 1):

A quick test shows that not doing a Serial.begin makes things run 10 times as fast. For example:

```c++
void setup ()
  {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  pinMode (13, OUTPUT);
  }  // end of setup

void loop ()
  {
  digitalWrite (13, HIGH);
  for (byte i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    Serial.println ("But does it get goat's blood out?");
  digitalWrite (13, LOW);
  delay (500);
  }  // end of loop
```

That took 292 ms to do 100 x of those prints on my Uno. If I comment out the Serial.begin call it takes 29 ms. So, faster but not incredibly fast.

On [my page about debugging](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11329) I have suggested code to turn on or off debugging prints. The basic idea is to have a Trace define that lets you output stuff if debugging is on, like this:

```c++
#define DEBUG false

// conditional debugging
#if DEBUG 

  #define beginDebug()  do { Serial.begin (115200); } while (0)
  #define Trace(x)      Serial.print   (x)
  #define Trace2(x,y)   Serial.print   (x,y)
  #define Traceln(x)    Serial.println (x)
  #define Traceln2(x,y) Serial.println (x,y)
  #define TraceFunc()   do { Serial.print (F("In function: ")); Serial.println (__PRETTY_FUNCTION__); } while (0)


#else
  #define beginDebug()  ((void) 0)
  #define Trace(x)      ((void) 0)
  #define Trace2(x,y)   ((void) 0)
  #define Traceln(x)    ((void) 0)
  #define Traceln2(x,y) ((void) 0)
  #define TraceFunc()   ((void) 0)
#endif // DEBUG


void setup ()
  {
  beginDebug ();
  pinMode (13, OUTPUT);
  }  // end of setup

void loop ()
  {
  digitalWrite (13, HIGH);
  for (byte i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    Traceln ("But does it get goat's blood out?");
  digitalWrite (13, LOW);
  delay (500);
  }  // end of loop
```

Now in this case, with DEBUG defined as `false`, the time taken with pin 13 high is now only 5 µs - a substantial speed-up.

If you define DEBUG to be true, then it is much slower - 290 ms as in the first test.

---

The suggestion made by KIIV will fail if you have `if` statements:

```c++
#ifdef NDEBUG
  #define LOG(...)
  #define LOGLN(...)
#else
  #define LOG(...) Serial.print(__VA_ARGS__);
  #define LOGLN(...) Serial.println(__VA_ARGS__);
#endif
```

For example:

```c++
if (something)
   LOG ("something is true");

digitalWrite (8, HIGH);
```

Imagine that debugging is off. Now the empty define makes the code look like:

```c++
if (something)
  digitalWrite (8, HIGH);
```

So you have a side-effect that the code behaves differently if debugging is off.

---

> Semicolon is not part of the macro, so it will be expanded into: `if (something) ;`

See [What does the c precompiler do with macros defined as (void)0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25021081/what-does-the-c-precompiler-do-with-macros-defined-as-void0) - there are subtle issues with using an empty define compared to void(0).

For example:

```
  Serial.println ("hi there"), LOGLN ("debugging");
```

That fails to compile (with the empty define) if debugging is off. The `void(0)` version does compile. Admittedly it's an edge case, but nevertheless ...

Comment: Semicolon is not part of the macro, so it will be expanded into:  `if (something) ;`

Comment: A way around the `if(...) [macro]` problem is, when debugging is turned off, to define your macros to equate to `{}`, such as `#define LOG(...) {}`, then the `if(...)` turns into `if(...) {}`

Comment: @Majenko But if you have: `#define MACRO() {}` and you'll use it as: `if (...) MACRO(...); else ...`  (notice that semicolon) it will turn into `if (...) {}; else ...`. That's why the pattern `do { ... } while(0)`  is used sometimes instead of simple block `{ ... }`

Comment: `Semicolon is not part of the macro` - you edited your post after I made mine. In your original post (as you can see from what I copied/pasted) you had semicolons.